# Poisson distribution woes... need some advice

Tags: probability

Garfield determined that the population of antidinosaurs on *Planet Antimater* is 552 antidinosaurs per square antimile.  Suppose Dr. Willard selects a random square antimile on the antiplanet.  Find the probability that this square antimile will have a population of 625 antidinosaurs.

Clearly $\lambda = 552$ and $X = 625$, thus..

$P(625, 552) = e^{-552}\frac{(552)^{625}}{625!}$

When I plugged this value into my computer, I might as well have hit it win antimatter.  It exploded.

Obviously, this will happen because of the values involved.  My question is.. how do we do this problem?  Is there a modified version of the Poisson formula for problems like this?

Comment: Use some approximation, e.g., Stirling's formula for the factorial in the denominator, or normal approximation to Poisson for large $\lambda$.  Alternatively, ask [Wolfy](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(-552)+(552)%5E625%2F(625!))

Comment: In addition to above, you can also consider taking $\log$ of both sides, and then exponentiating finally to get the answer. It seems to work for me.